# Creative SVG Mask

Tags: css, svg, mask

i want to create a mask over a picture using svg file.

it will use for header section, a header with 50% opacity mask over it.

but i have problem in responsive. in high resolutions, behind mask will empty and solid color, and in low resolutions, picture will overflow from mask.

please look at my try and help me.

```css
body{
  background:#eee;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
#header{
  position:relative;
  background:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531826267553-c4979aefab12?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80);
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-repeat: none;
  background-size:100% auto;
  background-position: 0 50%;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:200px;
}
#header:before {
  background: rgba(36, 55, 84, 0.5);
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#header:after {
  background:  url(https://svgshare.com/i/LSs.svg);
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  right: 0;
  top:calc(100% - 100px);
}
#header .header-content{
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 130px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
#header .header-content h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <div class="header-content">
        <h1>Welcome to our website</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your code like below using multiple background. Note that I have used the SVG inline and added `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to it

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(36, 55, 84, 0.5),rgba(36, 55, 84, 0.5)) top/100% calc(100% - 100px),
    url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 450 35" preserveAspectRatio="none" ><path opacity="0.5" fill="%23243754"  d="M0,35h1.333l417-15c0,0,31.666-1.001,31.666-20H0V35z"/><path fill="%23EEEEEE" d="M0,35h1.333l417-15c0,0,31.666-1.001,31.666-20L450,35H0z"/></svg>') bottom/100% 100px,
    url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531826267553-c4979aefab12?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80) center/cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}

#header .header-content {
  margin-top: 130px;
}

#header .header-content h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="header-content">
    <h1>Welcome to our website</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

But since it's supposed to work as a mask you should use it as mask like below. Only the second path of the SVG is needed (the part we need to hide)

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right,red,blue);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(36, 55, 84, 0.5),rgba(36, 55, 84, 0.5)),
    url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531826267553-c4979aefab12?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80) center/cover no-repeat;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  -webkit-mask:
     url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 450 35" preserveAspectRatio="none" ><path fill="black" d="M0,35h1.333l417-15c0,0,31.666-1.001,31.666-20L450,35H0z"/></svg>') bottom/100% 100px no-repeat,
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
  -webkit-mask-composite:destination-out;
  mask:
     url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 450 35" preserveAspectRatio="none" ><path fill="black" d="M0,35h1.333l417-15c0,0,31.666-1.001,31.666-20L450,35H0z"/></svg>') bottom/100% 100px no-repeat,
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
  mask-composite:exclude;
}

#header .header-content {
  margin-top: 130px;
}

#header .header-content h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="header-content">
    <h1>Welcome to our website</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, but i want reverse mask. in the section that now image is shown, i want 100% transparency to show body background and in gradient section , i want picture, can you help me?

Comment: `mask-composite:exclude;` solved my problem, thanks a lot

Comment: @Rezaghasemi oops, I was testing on chrome and forget Firefox.Yes you have to use exclude and not intersect

Comment: just a small question, i want load svg external, it's possible? i tried and not success.

Comment: @Rezaghasemi there is some security issue that will prevent the use of SVG inside mask. I also face this. See this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394277/8620333